# Files received via Bluetooth with root as the owner

Tags: permissions, bluetooth, 16.10, blueman

I have an Ubuntu Studio 16.10 with Cinnamon. I can't receive files via Bluetooth from my phone so that I be the owner of those files:

- when both `blueman-applet` and `obexd` are run by me, I can enable file receiving in `blueman-services` and I can specify which folder I wish to receive the files, but receiving itself files fail the very moment they are sent from an external device (eg. phone)
- when `obex` is run by `root` but `blueman` is run by me, I can't enable the file receive feature, let alone specify the destination folder
- when both `obex` and `blueman` are run by `root`, I can enable file receive, I can specify the destination folder, I can even receive files, yet the files arrive with `0600 root:root` privilege. I can sort it out with `chown`, but I can't expect the same from a user with no such knowledge every time they're sending files over BT.

I'm thinking of setting up `inotify` to watch the BT destination folder and whenever a new file arrives execute `chown` in the background but I believe there must be a better solution aimed at the problem itself instead of the symptoms.

Is there a specific setting I'm missing here?

Comment: Permission/ownership on the target folder?

Comment: @waltinator the folder belongs to the user (it's inside their home folder).

Comment: There was a bug that was fixed do you have a version that does this: https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/275

Comment: No, mine is not doing anything like that. I also did a chown g+s on the folder just to be sure, but of no use. Files keep arriving with 0600 root:root.